# How to read a local file in a JavaScript console program line by line?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a local JavaScript program to read a file, process it's contents and format the text line by line, store it in an array and also display it on the console.

I'm using NodeJS.

I don't need any assistance in the later steps. The problem is that the code posted everywhere runs on a browser. I'm looking for something that runs locally by directly picking up the file from the local address on the disk and displays the contents on a windows command prompt like interface.

Comment: `nodejs` is what you are looking for

Comment: here is the link https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Setup a node.js server and use readFile() function from 'fs' module -> fs.readFile() to read a file from local system. And can you share link of code posted where file is read in browser console. How's it even possible, I'am curious.

Comment: JavaScript has no native way to read files. It depends on the host environment providing an API. You haven't said what host environment you are using. Is it Node.js? Is it Windows Scripting Host? Is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Import
var fs = require('fs');

// File path
fileName = <File name with path>;

// Read Function
fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This reads the file asynchronously from a file on the disk.